# How to compare two elements of the same but unconstrained generic type for equality?

Tags: c#, generics, class, struct, equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)

I've got the following generic class and the compiler complains that "`Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TValue' and 'TValue'`" (see [CS0019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63h61ky.aspx)):

```
public class Example<TValue>
{
    private TValue _value;
    public TValue Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (_value != value) // <<-- ERROR
            {
                _value= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I constrain `TValue` to `class`, I could use `Object.Equals()`. Since I need this for boths structs and classes I'd be very happy if I could avoid that though.

So the question is, how can I compare two elements of the same but unconstrained generic type for equality?

Comment: Why can't you use .Equals for value types?

Comment: By default, if you call "object.Equals(a, b)" on reference types, then "object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)" will be called.

Comment: @TcKs: By default, you cannot be sure if Equals has been overriden in a derived class.

Comment: @Iepie: Yes, and if is overriden the equality operator (and Equals method), then this methods should know how to compare two object better than default implementation. So it should returns correct resutls.

Comment: @Tcks: True, brainfart on my part :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
public class Example<TValue>
{
    private TValue _value;
    public TValue Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {

            if (!object.Equals(_value, value))
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx says that by default value types will be compared bitwise, else the Equals() method is used. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that this will incur boxing penalties for value types.

Answer (score 7):

Three options:

- Constrain TValue to implement `IEquatable<TValue>` and then call `x.Equals(y)`
- Take another parameter of type `IEqualityComparer<TValue>` and use that
- Use `EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default` to perform the comparisons

You could always mix and match options 2 and 3, of course - default to the default comparer, but also allow a specific one to be provided.

Answer (score 2):

- Equals() for value types
- ReferenceEquals() for reference types

Comment: I'd rather avoid having to reflect or otherwise distinguish the two cases. Currently I'm using an abstract base and implement these bits twice :-/

Comment: What reflection are you using? Doing a typeof(TValue) is a compile time constant, and checking that type wont really cost anything.

Answer (score 1):

Is IComparable an option?

```
public class Example<TValue> where TValue: IComparable
{
    private TValue _value;
    public TValue Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {

            if (_value.CompareTo(value) != 0)
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `!=` operator cannot be applied here because there are cases where it can't be used. For instance, `!=` can't be used for comparing structs, unless the compare operators (`==` `!=`) are overloaded.

Of course, you can compare language structs, like `int != int`, but I'm not sure how this is implemented.

So, because TValue can be a *custom* struct, it cannot use the `!=` operator.

Comment: Yes, that was my understanding of CS0019 too.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool operator ==(EntityBase<T> entity1, EntityBase<T> entity2)
        {
            if ((object)entity1 == null && (object)entity2 == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if ((object)entity1 == null || (object)entity2 == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(entity1.Id, entity2.Id) != 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```