# Can Not Compare Generic Values

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am creating a generic class to hold widgets and I am having trouble implementing the contains method:

```
public class WidgetBox<A,B,C>
{
    public bool ContainsB(B b)
    {
        // Iterating thru a collection of B's
        if( b == iteratorB )  // Compiler error.
        ...
    }
}
```

**Error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'V' and 'V'**

If I can not compare types, how am I to implement contains?  How do dictionaries, lists, and all of the other generic containers do it??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few options here

The first is to use `Object.Equals`:

```
if(b.Equals(iteratorB)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Be careful using this option; if `B` does not override `Object.Equals` then the default comparsion is reference equality when `B` is a reference type and value equality when `B` is a value type. This might not be the behavior that you are seeking and is why without additional information I would consider one of the next two options.

The second is to add a constraint that `B` is `IComparable`:

```
public class WidgetBox<A, B, C> where B : IComparable
```

so that

```
if(b.CompareTo(iteratorB) == 0) {
    // do stuff
}
```

A third is to require an `IEqualityComparer<B>` be passed to the constructor of `WidgetBox`

```
public class WidgetBox<A, B, C> {
    IEqualityComparer<B> _comparer;
    public WidgetBox(IEqualityComparer<B> comparer) {
        _comparer = comparer;
    }
    // details elided
}
```

Then:

```
if(_comparer.Equals(b, iteratorB)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

With this last option you can provide an overload that defaults to `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`:

```
public WidgetBox() : this(EqualityComparer<T>.Default) { }
```

Comment: Depending on the type and whether you only care about equality (vs less than/greater than/equal/etc) it is typically much more efficient to use an IEqualityComparer as opposed to IComparer since equality can often be ruled out very quickly such as with strings of different lengths.

Answer (score 3):

Not all objects implement == but all will have Equals (although it may be inherited from Object.Equals).

```
public class WidgetBox<A,B,C>
{
    public bool ContainsB(B b)
    {
        // Iterating thru a collection of B's
        if( b.Equals(iteratorB) )
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to Jason's answer, you can also add `where T : IEquatable<T>` rather than `IComparable`. This provides an overload of the `Equals` method that accepts a `T` parameter.

```
public class WidgetBox<A,B,C> where B : IEquatable<B>
{
    public bool ContainsB(B b)
    {
        // Iterating thru a collection of B's
        if( b.Equals(iteratorB) )
        ...
    }
}
```

This might be preferable to simply using the supplied `Object.Equals` method, since that checks for the equivalence of two object *references* (I believe) and so might not provide quite the functionality you want (e.g., if you want two `Person` objects with the same `SSN` property to be regarded as equal, or something like that).

But to answer your question of "how do all the .NET collections do it," I believe the `Equals` method (no constraint) is your answer.

Answer (score 2):

At compile-time, there is no guarantee that the type in the type argument B provides an equality operator.

Instead, you can do this:

```
var comparer = EqualityComparer<B>.Default;
foreach (B item in items) {
    if ( comparer.Equals(b, item) ) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (b != null)
    if (b.Equals(iteratorB))
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with it in your case then all it takes is a class constraint on B

```
public class WidgetBox<A,B,C> where B : class
```

that will eliminate the problem