# Using overloaded operator== in a generic function

Tags: c#, generics

Consider the following code:

```
class CustomClass
{
    public CustomClass(string value)
        { m_value = value; }

    public static bool operator ==(CustomClass a, CustomClass b)
        { return a.m_value == b.m_value; }

    public static bool operator !=(CustomClass a, CustomClass b)
        { return a.m_value != b.m_value; }

    public override bool Equals(object o)
        { return m_value == (o as CustomClass).m_value; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
        { return 0; /* not needed */ }

    string m_value;
}

class G
{
    public static bool enericFunction1<T>(T a1, T a2) where T : class
        { return a1.Equals(a2); }
    public static bool enericFunction2<T>(T a1, T a2) where T : class
        { return a1==a2; }
}
```

Now when I call both generic functions, **one succeeds and one fails**:

```
var a = new CustomClass("same value");
var b = new CustomClass("same value");
Debug.Assert(G.enericFunction1(a, b)); // Succeeds
Debug.Assert(G.enericFunction2(a, b)); // Fails
```

Apparently, G.enericFunction2 executes the default operator== implementation instead of my override. Can anybody explain why this happens?

Comment: Saying `a1.Equals(a2)` calls a **virtual** instance method. Even if the overload is fixed at compile-time (to `System.Object.Equals(System.Object)`), at run-time it's always the overridden method that gets called. That's what virtual methods are all about. Saying `a1 == a2` calls a `static` method (at least formally there exists a method `public static bool operator ==(object x, object y) { ... }`). The overload of `==` to call is fixed at compile-time, and since `T` is not constrained to something matching your custom `==`, the only thing the compiler can choose is the `object` version `==`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

> When applying the where T : class constraint, avoid the == and != operators on the type parameter because these operators will test for reference identity only, not for value equality. This is the case even if these operators are overloaded in a type that is used as an argument. (...) The reason for this behavior is that, at compile time, the compiler only knows that T is a reference type, and therefore must use the default operators that are valid for all reference types.

Answer (score 0):

If I change the `enericFunction2` to:

```
    public static bool enericFunction2<T>(T a1, T a2) where T : class
    {
        object aa = a1;
        CustomClass obj1 = (CustomClass)aa;

        object bb = a2;
        CustomClass obj2 = (CustomClass)bb;

        return obj1 == obj2; 
    }
```

Then everything works fine. But I am afraid I can't explain it. I mean `a1` and `a2` know their type. Why a cast is needed to the `CustomClass`, so the operators are called?

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use a generic type instead of the fixed type CustomClass.