# Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Tags: c#, generics, generic-method

My application defines several `enum`s that include the `[Flags]` attribute.

I wanted to write a small utility method to check if a flag was set for any of those `enum`s and I came up with the following.

```
protected static bool IsFlagSet<T>(ref T value, ref T flags)
{
    return ((value & flags) == flags);
}
```

But this gives me the error "Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'".

Can this be made to work?

Comment: There is no need for those `ref` modifiers.

Comment: Well, okay. They were used in the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb(v=vs.80).aspx. I assumed so they would work efficiently with large value types.

Comment: An enum will never be large enough to make this an optimization. In Swap() they are functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

& is an operator on a class type. Which means that the class T has to have a method that overloads the operator &.

.Net can't expect that every class will have it. So it fails.

What you can do, is make a base class, that declares the operator overload as a method.

Then use [**Constraints**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx#Y627) to declare that T uses that base class:

```
protected static bool IsFlagSet<T> where T: BaseclassWithAnd (ref T value, ref T flags)
{
    return ((value & flags) == flags);
}
```

Comment: How do I define an interface with an operator overload??

Comment: i dont think you can define operators in interfaces, only in classes. but i might be wrong

Comment: My bad, can't do interface with static method. You could make a base class though. Another option is making a method And() that can be called from the template.

Comment: Enums are not classes, I don't think you can get this to compile/work

Comment: For this to work, you'd need to state `where T : Enum` as the type constraint, but this isn't supported - there's even a specific C# compiler error message for exactly this case.

Answer (score 15):

The Enum class already has a utility function: `Enum.HasFlag(Flag f)`, see the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx)

```
 if (petsInFamily.HasFlag(Pet.Dog))
        familiesWithDog++;
```

Note: This was introduced in C# 4. 
And while it's very readable it may have some performance issues.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I had missed this one and will use it instead of my original approach. However, I feel I should accept an answer that more specifically answers my question.

Comment: +1 - use Enum.HasFlag if you can use .Net 4.0

Comment: @Alexei: Ahh, new to .NET 4.0? That explains how I missed it. (Why didn't they add `SetFlag()` while they were at it?)

Comment: @Alexei: You're right, I looked and it's also listed for Fx 3.5 but that is probably an error.

Comment: Note that `HasFlag` is implemented using Reflection, so consider any possible performance impact. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2011/01/28/enum-hasflag-good-or-bad.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I understand that my answer is too late, but I found really amazing solution of this problem.
Starting from .Net 4 we can use `dynamic` types in C#. You method can be rewritten:

```
protected static bool IsFlagSet<T>(T value, T flags)
{
    dynamic a = value;
    dynamic b = flags;
    return ((a & b) == flags);
}
```

Idea behind that `dynamic` allows you postpone to runtime if method/operator supported by type `T`. So if `&` is defined for `T` then runtime is success.

Answer (score 2):

You must type-cast it to a type that defines the & operation.

```
    protected static bool IsFlagSet<T>(ref T value, ref T flags)
    {
        return ((Convert.ToInt32(value) & Convert.ToInt32(flags)) == Convert.ToInt32(flags));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the error is that you can't restric generic type as "have operator X defined for T,T". As result C# has to assume that there is no operator X defined for T,T and shows an error.

This is behavior often discussed in relation to == operator - i.e. [Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c), but applies to all operators.

For full list of possible constrints see - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=VS.100).aspx, note that there is no constraint for Enum (that would be useful for your scenario specifically) nor for types with operator X defined.