# Why can't I compare a KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> with default

Tags: c#, .net, key-value

In .Net 2.5 I can usually get an equality comparison (==) between a value and its type default

```
if (myString == default(string))
```

However I get the following exception when I try to run an equality comparison on a default KeyValuePair and a KeyValuePair

Code Sample (from a pre-extension method, proto-lambda static ListUtilities class :) )

```
public static TKey 
        FirstKeyOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> lookups, 
                   Predicate<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> predicate)
{
    KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair = FirstOrDefault(lookups, predicate);

    return pair == default(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>) ? 
                   default(TKey) : pair.Key;
}
```

Exception:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to
>   operands of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>'
>   and
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>'

Is it because, as a struct, the KeyValuePair is not nullable? If this is the case, why, as, presumably, default was implemented to handle not nullable types?

**EDIT**

For the record, I chose @Chris Hannon as selected answer, as he gave me what I was looking for, the most elegant option, and a succinct explanation, however I do encourage reading @Dasuraga for a very comprehensive explanation as to why this is the case

Comment: FirstOrDefault<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>(lookups, predicate) ?

Comment: @Jean-Bernard Pellerin, that should be inferred from the passed type, or the compiler would've complained. The exception also happens when you simplify it to myKvp == default(KeyValuePair<...>)

Comment: Surely defaults are pitched at scalar types? What does it *mean* for a KVP to have a default value? I imagine you do have an answer for this in the context of whatever it is you're trying to build. I suspect that for non-scalars the default is whatever you get from calling the nil constructor. In this case I would expect object identity comparison to return false since you get a new object each time the constructor is invoked.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This happens because `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` does not define a custom == operator and is not included in the predefined list of value types that can use it.

Here is a link to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for that operator.

> For predefined value types, the equality operator (==) returns true if the values of its operands are equal, false otherwise.

Your best bet for an equality check in this case, because this is not a struct you have control over, is to call `default(KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>).Equals(pair)` instead.

Comment: But doesn't equals check if the Objects are equal, i.e. if the references refer to the same object? I'm not sure if default(int).Equals(0)...

Comment: @Dasuraga Console.WriteLine(default(int).Equals(0)); outputs 'true'. I am thinking on value types, the value is compared on Equals, otherwise it seems pointless to have an Equals method on them

Comment: @Dasuraga `==` (and every other operator) is *non-virtual*. `(object)kvp1 == (object)kvp2` would perform a reference equality. The cast is important to *change the compile-time type* to ensure that `object.==(object)` is invoked, which *is* a defined operator.

Comment: @Dasuraga when equals is called on a struct it is actually the instance method of ValueType that is called, not the instance method of Object. ValueType's instance method Equals uses reflection to check whether all fields are equal. ref:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173110.aspx

Answer (score 6):

(If you don't care about the generics discussion linked to this error, you can just jump to the end for your "real" answer)

As the error says, there is no equality testing for KeyValuePairs (i.e. there is no built-in comparison method). The reason for this is to avoid having to place constraints on the types of KeyValuePairs (there are many cases where key,value comparisons would never be made).

Obviously if you want to compare thes KeyValuePairs, I'd imagine what you'd want is to check if the keys and values are equal. But this implies a whole mess of things , notably that TKey and TValue are both comparable types (ie they implement the IComparable interface)

You could write your own comparison function between keyvaluepairs, for example:

```
static bool KeyValueEqual<TKey , TValue>(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> fst, 
                                          KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> snd) 
                                         where  TValue:IComparable
                                         where  TKey:IComparable
        {
            return (fst.Value.CompareTo(snd.Value)==0)
                     && (snd.Key.CompareTo(fst.Key)==0);
        }
```

(Excuse the awful indentation)

Here we impose that TKey and TValue are both comparable (via the CompareTo member function).

The CompareTo function (as defined for pre-defined types) returns 0 when two objects are equal , à la strcmp  .  a.ComparesTo(b)==0 means a and b are the "same"(in value, not the same object).

so this function would take two KVPs (k,v) and (k',v') and would return true if and only if k==k' and v==v' (in the intuitive sense).

---

But is this necessary? It seems your test where you're having problems is based on some sort of verification on the return of FirstOrDefault.

But there's a reason your function's called [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx):

> Returns the first element of the
>   sequence that satisfies a condition or
>   a **default** value if **no such element is
>   found.**

(emphasis mine)

This function **returns default values if something isn't found**, meaning if your predicate isn't verified you'll get a KeyValuePair equal to (default(TKey),default(TValue).

Your code therefore (intends to) check whether pair.Key==default(TKey), only to **return default(TKey) anyways**. Wouldn't it just make more sense to return pair.Key from the outset?

Comment: Very nice answer, and your workaround was precisely the path I was going down until @Chris Hannon pointed out using Equals(). Refer to my comment to your comment on that answer is response to your concern that Equals would not work on a value type. I guess, however, should be defensive and assume that there is some edge condition I am not considering ...

Answer (score 4):

In order you to use the "==" equality operator on any class or struct, it needs to override the operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

KeyValuePair doesn't, and therefore you get the compile error. Note, you'll get the same error if you just try this:

```
var k1 = new KeyValuePair<int,string>();
var k2 = new KeyValuePair<int,string>();

bool b = k1 == k2; //compile error
```

**EDIT:** As Eric Lippert corrected me in the comments, classes obviously don't need to override the equality operator for "==" to be valid. It'll compile fine and do a reference equality check. My mistake.

Comment: **Any** class or struct -- really?  What if you make your own class C; can you compare two instances of C for equality without defining a custom == operator?

Answer (score 3):

It fails for the same reason as the following:

```
var kvp = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("a","b");
var res = kvp == kvp;
```

The clue is in the error message, naturally. (It has nothing to do with `default`).

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>' and 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>'
```

The operator `==` is not defined for `KeyValuePair<T,U>`.

Error messages FTW.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Defaults are pitched at scalar types.

Ask yourself this question: What does it *mean* for KVP to have a default value?

For non-scalars the default is whatever you get from calling the nil constructor. Assuming that KVP Equals performs instance identity comparison, I would expect it to return false since you get a new object each time the constructor is invoked.

Comment: In an ideal world, I would expected `new KVP("Hello", "World") == new KVP("Hello", "World")` to compile. However, to ensure the `==` contract down (`a.Key == b.Key && a.Value == b.Value`) this would require that generic arguments also responded to `==`, which cannot be enforced at compile time. Remember -- each type, custom structures include, have a default value.

Answer (score 1):

This goes in a slightly different direction, but I am presuming you queried a Dictionary to get this result, and then you want to check if it returned a valid result or not.

I found the better method of doing this was to query out the actual value instead of the whole KeyValuePair, like this:

var valitem = MyDict.Values.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Something == aVar);

Now you can  check if valitem is null or not. Again, it doesn't directly answer your question, but offers what might be a alternative approach to your intended goal.