# Finding children in node structure using generic key?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)

I have a "GenericNode"-parent/child structure that I'm trying to make a Find method for.

```
public class GenericNode<TKey, TName>
{
  private GenericNode<TKey, TName> parent;
  private readonly TKey key;
  private readonly TName name;
  private readonly ICollection<GenericNode<TKey, TName>> children;

  public GenericNode(TKey key, TName name) {
    this.key = key;
    this.name = name;
    children = new Collection<GenericNode<TKey, TName>>();
  }

  // AddChild etc...

  public GenericNode<TKey, TName> GetChildNodeById(TKey keyToFind)
  {
    return FindChild(node => node.key == keyToFind); // <--- THIS WON'T COMPILE
  }

  private GenericNode<TKey, TName> FindChild(Func<GenericNode<TKey, TName>, Boolean> matcher)
  {
    // Recursive search returning first matching node...
  }
}
```

The above (C# .NET 3.5) doesn't work because it can't compare `node.key` to `keyToFind` in the `GetChildNodeById`-method. I've been trying different generic constraints etc without luck. How can I specify that the TKey:s are the same type?

I could just create a derived class with a Guid for key and move the GetChildNodeById to that class but I would like a generic solution if possible. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6380001/555547. Changing `==` to `.Equals()` compiled it for me. Good luck!

Comment: I'm an idiot, Equals() did the trick and Raphaëls link explained why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve this:

1. Make a constraint so that `TKey : IComprabale`, then in `GetNodeByKey` you can call `Compare` on the key.
2. Make a constraint so that `TKey : IEquatable<TKey>`, then you can call `Equals` on the key.
3. Instead of using the equality operator, call `Equals` on the key. Note that you risk a `NullReferenceException` that way, and that in order to check the key for null you need to add a constraint `TKey : class`.
4. Call `Object.Equals` on the keys. Note that this has a performance hit if your keys are value types, because in the call to `Object.Equals` they will be boxed.
5. Let the user of the tree class provide his comparer. I would recommend adopting the pattern of standard .NET collections. For example look at the different constructors of `Dictionary` that can take a comparer.

Comment: @lukas - Except I'm on .NET 3.5, otherwise good idea.

Comment: Also, excellent pointers, I will explore the options you've listed, thanks!

Comment: dynamics are nice but have 2 big problems: 1. they are not type safe so errors are found at runtime instead of in compile time, 2. they are very slow.