# Compare two instances of an object

Tags: c#, object, comparison

I'm not really sure if what I'm looking for exists, but here it goes,

```
    public class OptionType : IComp
    {
        public static readonly FIXTag Tag = 201;

        public enum Types
        {
            Put = 'P',
            Call = 'C'
        }

        private abstract class CharValues
        {
            public const char Put  = '0';
            public const char Call = '1';
        }

        public abstract class ByteValues
        {
            public const byte Put = (byte)CharValues.Put;
            public const byte Call = (byte)CharValues.Call;
        }

        #region Instances
        public readonly Types Type;
        public readonly DataOptionType DataType;
        public readonly OptionType InverseType;
        public readonly char CharValue;
        public readonly byte ByteValue;

        private OptionType(Types Type, DataOptionType DataType, FIX.OptionType InverseType, char CharValue, byte ByteValue)
        {
            this.Type        = Type;
            this.DataType    = DataType;
            this.InverseType = InverseType;
            this.CharValue   = CharValue;
            this.ByteValue   = ByteValue;

            if (InverseType == null)
            {
                this.InverseType = (Type == Types.Call)
                    ? new OptionType(Types.Put, DataOptionType.Put, this, CharValues.Put, ByteValues.Put)
                    : new OptionType(Types.Call, DataOptionType.Call, this, CharValues.Call, ByteValues.Call);
            }
        }

        public static OptionType Put = new OptionType(Types.Put, DataOptionType.Put, FIX.OptionType.Call, CharValues.Put, ByteValues.Put);
        public static OptionType Call = new OptionType(Types.Call, DataOptionType.Call, FIX.OptionType.Put, CharValues.Call, ByteValues.Call);
        #endregion
```

I basically want to be able to have the following code return true,

```
    if (FIX.OptionType.Call == FIX.OptionType.Put.InverseType)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
```

Is there some interface or something that I can implement?  Is doing == the same in this instance as doing `.Equals` or `.CompareTo`?

Thanks in advanced!

William

### Update

I want to make sure that I am implementing all of the overloads/operators correctly - so let me know what you think -

```
        public static bool operator== (FIX.OptionType ValueA, FIX.OptionType ValueB)
        {
            return (ValueA.Type != ValueB.Type) ? true : false;
        }

        public static bool operator!= (FIX.OptionType ValueA, FIX.OptionType ValueB)
        {
            return (ValueA.Type != ValueB.Type) ? true : false;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return (obj != null && obj is FIX.OptionType && (obj as FIX.OptionType).Type == Type)
                ? true
                : false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (int)Type;
        }
```

Comment: (this refers specifically to your update) You do not need to implement overloads: you are building a smart enum, so all you need is to clean up your instance creation code just slightly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this : on each method you test your value to return

```
public class myClass
    {
        public static bool operator== (myClass a, myClass b)
        {
            bool _bResult = false;

            // your code..

            return _bResult;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(myClass a, myClass b)
        {
            bool _bResult = false;

            // your code..

            return _bResult;
        }

    }
```

You can see other sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/s53ehcz3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Since each instance contains an enum which is what i would use to compare it with, is there any way that I could just set it so that it automatically uses the value of that enum for comparison?

Comment: To compare all property you can use 'System.Reflection' do a foearch with PropertyInfo

Answer (score 0):

You can use Generics.
Take a look into tgis example:

```
public bool IsDataChanged<T>()
{           
    T value1 = GetValue2;
    T value2 = GetValue1();

    return !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(valueInDB, valueFromView);
}
```

And read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c) for some additional information.