# How to make binary multiplication operator * available in a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

```
abstract class Shape<T>
{
    public abstract T Area();
}
class Square<T> : Shape<T>
{
    T side;
    public Square(T side)
    {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public override T Area()
    {
        return this.side * this.side;
    }
}
```

> Error 1   Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and of type 'T'.

Compiler throws an error because there is no `*` for `this.side*this.side`. How to make the binary multiplication operator `*` available in a generic class?

Comment: Have you seen [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html)?

Comment: also this is somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6317290d-bbfb-46f6-812b-7f4252ce3f27/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-t-and-t

Comment: I don't believe you will get around using lot of if-s. One thing though that comes into my mind to simplify this would be delegating multiplication and `return dlgMultiply<T>(x, y);`

Comment: I like answer with code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `*` operator itself, but you can work around it by generating an expression that uses this operator:

```
static class Operators
{
    public static T Multiply<T>(T x, T y)
    {
        return OperatorCache<T>.Multiply(x, y);
    }

    static class OperatorCache<T>
    {
        static OperatorCache()
        {
            Multiply = MakeBinaryOperator(ExpressionType.Multiply);
        }

        static Func<T, T, T> MakeBinaryOperator(ExpressionType type)
        {
            var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            var y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "y");
            var body = Expression.MakeBinary(type, x, y);
            var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(body, x, y);
            return expr.Compile();
        }

        public readonly static Func<T, T, T> Multiply;


    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
public override T Area()
{
    return Operators.Multiply(this.side, this.side);
}
```

Of course you can add other operators to the `Operators` class; just keep in mind that **if the operator you're using is not defined for `T`, it will fail at runtime**.

Comment: I think the last sentence should be bold :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. The multiplication operator is not defined for all types. But your generic has no constraints so the compiler has to assume that the consumers of your class can use any type, like `string` for example.

Unfortunately, generic constraints in .NET can't be used to express this kind of requirement, i.e. there is no way to constrain `T` to only types that define the multiplication operator.

Bottom line is: You can't use generics in your scenario. You need to go the same way as the .NET framework with its [`Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.aspx) (for `double`) and [`SizeF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.sizef.aspx) (for `float`) types.

Note about the context of my answer:
If you want to provide your class for arbitrary classes you have control over, Alexey has the correct answer.
However, his answer does not apply if you want to use your `Square` class with types like `double`, `float` or `int`, because you can't add an interface to them.

Answer (score 3):

You can substitute it with a method `.Multiply(T a, T b)`
And use it with interface

```
public interface IMultiplyable<T>
{
     T Multiply(T a, T b);
}
```

Comment: Can we define an operator `*` in a generic class?

Comment: No there is no constraint for generic class to have operator overloads