# Generic constraint for comparison

Tags: c#, generics

I have this code which does not compile

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public bool AreEqual(T a, T b)
    {
        return a == b;
    }
}
```

The error is

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

That makes sence because T could be something that does not implement any operators.
Anyway, what do I have to do to make this work?

I know I could rewrite my code to avoid the `==` operator, but that's not the question.

**Update**

After reading the current answers, just to make it more clear. I know how I could rewrite my code but what I wanted to know was more like.

*Is there a way that allows me to use the `==` operator in my generic class. Something like `public class MyClass<T> where T : ==`*

Comment: Why can't you just do: `a.Equals(b);` Am I missing something ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `I know I could rewrite my code to avoid the == operator, but that's not the question`, but have you thought about `Object.Equals(a, b)`?

Comment: No. C# constraints do not allow operator or other static member constraints. If you require this, you may want to look at F# which does allow that sort of thing.

Comment: @Alexei - The first link helped a lot, bottom line: If you have a `where T : class` generic constraint this works but I expect T to be either a ValueType or an ObjectType so there is no possibility to allow the use of the == operator

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `Object.Equals` method:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public bool AreEqual(T a, T b)
    {
        return Object.Equals(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: This relies on the `T` overriding `object.Equals` (which is probably a good idea in this case anyway).

Answer (score 2):

what is T supposed to represent ?

Docu to help with adding the constraint
[Constraints docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

**EDIT: To clarify my point for down voter.**
`using return Equals(a, b);`
clearly makes sense, especially for reference types.
So `Object.Equals` is fine as the answer.
And using Equals versus == is important to understand.

But for the down voter. Did you consider ?

this will compile:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T:class 
{
    public bool AreEqual(T a, T b) 
    {
         return a == b;
    }
}
```

Suggesting someone consider constraints isnt wrong. It just isnt what they "needed" to know.
My bad for not knowing poster didnt know about Equals()   :-)

[Another SO post that goes into more detail on `==` and constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)

Comment: shame people are too scared to say why