# Use == operator with generic type in a Where Linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda, operators

I am trying to generate a SQL query (as a string) using the [SQLinq library](http://sqlinq.codeplex.com/). The code context is a generic class that creates the query with a `Where` clause in it.

```
public string Get<TEntity, TId>(TId id)
    where TEntity: IHasAnIdField<TId>
{
    var query = new SQLinq<TEntity>();

    // The following statement does not compile due to error in lambda with "==" operator
    // "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TId' and 'TId'"
    query = query.Where((Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)(i => i.Id == id));

    var sql = query.ToSQL().ToQuery();
    return sql;
}
```

Adding a `where TId: class` generic constraint resolves the problem but since my TId are in most cases value types (mainly `int`, `long`, `Guid`) it does not match my needs. And the generic constraint `where TId: struct` does not make it compile. I understand the reasons why this happens (thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)).

The interface for the entity is

```
public interface IHasAnIdField<TId>
{
    TId Id { get; }
}
```

I cannot use a `.Equal(..)` call or any `EqualityComparer` since a method call in the Expression tree is not handled by the SQLinq tool.

How can I inform the compiler that my TId is compatible with the `==` operator?

Comment: I don't see how `i.Id` resolves, since there's nothing to say that `TEntity` has an `Id` property; am I missing something?

Comment: @Tim you are right. I tried to simplify the code before submitting. I simplified a bit too much. My bad. It's fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: try `where TId: IEquatable<TId>`

Comment: @Grundy that would ensure that `i.Id.Equals(id)` could work if run in C#, but it sounds like SQLinq wouldn't understand that.

Comment: @Grundy, @Tim: Grundy is right. It's question of Expression tree here, not really of how it is compared in C# (since it's only goal is to be translated in a SQL string with a SQL operator `=`)

Comment: Have you tried combining a `IEquatable<TKey>` constraint on `TKey` together with `.Equals()`?

Comment: @DannyVarod yes I did. And it doesn't work since SQLinq Expression tree handling does not support method call.

Comment: The additional constraint enables many frameworks to translate the .Equals() into a built in comparison, however, in your case, you may need to switch framework.

Comment: @DannyVarod: do you have any suggestions? My friend google always answers me `SQLinq` (small, fast, just the string sql query needed)

Comment: For LINQ queries above SQL I prefer Entity Framework, as it gives you some level of abstraction from the database with many advanced features and a large user community. For NoSQL based database there are more flexible alternatives. Speed is not usually an issue if your LINQ is reasonable and you cache where possible - the overhead of EF isn't usually significant in the overall measurements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could build the expression manually:

```
public string Get<TEntity, TId>(TId id)
    where TEntity: IHasAnIdField<TId>
{
    var query = new SQLinq<TEntity>();

    // predicate: i => i.Id == id    
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "i");
    var predicate =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(arg, "Id"),
                Expression.Constant(id))
            arg);


    query = query.Where(predicate);
    var sql = query.ToSQL().ToQuery();
    return sql;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I have multiple parameters, how to use ?

 
 query = query.Where(predicate).Where(x=>x.IsDeleted); It's Okey ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the new [`DynamicSQLinq`](http://sqlinq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SQLinq/SQLinq/Dynamic/DynamicSQLinq.cs) class. Some examples can be seen in the [unit tests for it](http://sqlinq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SQLinq/SQLinqTest/Dynamic/DynamicSQLinqTest.cs) that SQLinq has. In your case, it might look like:

```
public string Get<TEntity, TId>(TId id)
where TEntity : IHasAnIdField<TId>
{
    var query = new DynamicSQLinq(typeof(TEntity).Name);

    query = query.Where("Id = @0", id);

    var sql = query.ToSQL().ToQuery();
    return sql;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in EF, I got it working by adding the IEquatable interface constraint which causes it to use the strong typed Equals method.

```
public string Get<TEntity, TId>(TId id)
    where TEntity: IHasAnIdField<TId>, IEquatable<TId>
{
    var query = new SQLinq<TEntity>();

    // The following statement does not compile due to error in lambda with "==" operator
    // "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TId' and 'TId'"
    query = query.Where((Expression>)(i => i.Id == id));

    var sql = query.ToSQL().ToQuery();
    return sql;
}
```