# How to compare two values in generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, comparison

I need to create generic method which returns greater of two params. Operators > and < don't work. Here is signature of my method:

```
public static T Greater<T>(ref T a, ref T b)
{
    if (a > b) 
    {
       return a;
    }
    else 
    {
       return b;
    }
}
```

I'm quite rookie in C# and totally new in generic types.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c.

Comment: As a non related comment, to shorten your method you can write: `return a.CompareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;`

Comment: These aren't quite duplicates. Those are about comparing equality. This question is about order / precedence.

Comment: Not related to your question, but why are those `ref`s there? They don't seem necessary, since you're not modifying the parameters.

Answer (score 10):

Since the `T` can be any type there is no guarantee that `T` will overload `>` or `<` operators. Adding a `IComparable<T>` constraint you are saying that `T` must implement `IComparable<T>` which contains a method named [`CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht(v=vs.110).aspx), then you can use that method to compare your objects instead:

```
public static T Greater<T>(ref T a, ref T b) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if(a.CompareTo(b) > 0) return a;
    else return b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. With your help learning C# is easier! :)