# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Type?' and 'Type?'

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I have a class like this:

```
public class Article {

private Category? category;
private string content;

public Article(Category? category,string content){
      Contract.Ensures(this.category == category); // error

   }
}
```

but on `Ensure` method this error occurs:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Category?' and 'Category?'

How can I avoid that?

Comment: What is `Category`?  Has it overloaded the `==` operator?

Comment: no, I didn't even implemented it!

Comment: Well then there you go.  The operator you haven't defined doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you aware of the consequences of making Category a struct instead of a class?

Comment: If you don't know, then you should be using a `class`.

Comment: Structs are value-types, which behave very differently to reference types (classes) in certain circumstances. This can cause a lot of confusion. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) is one reference you may wish to read. But as @Servy says, if you don't know what you're getting into, just use `class`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to overload the `==` operator for that type if you expect to be able to use it to compare two instances (whether nullable or not) of that type.

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
this.category.Equals(category)
```

Comment: Unlikely that will help unless he overrode that function

Comment: every object inherits the Equals method from the parent class object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, it does. However, the default implementation is *terrible* and not very useful.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Why would he need to override this method?  It's a value type, not a reference type.  It does not check whether the two instances are referencing the same object, but rather if the values two structs hold are equal.

Comment: @B.K. Ah, missed the value type. In that case, a memberwise-comparison will *probably* be ok. It could be an issue if he had reference member types that needed custom comparers though.

Answer (score 0):

first please **implement** **Equals** inside **Category** class

```
public struct Category // turned out that Category is a struct
{
    public int Field {get; set; } // for demo purpose only

    public override bool Equals(Object that) 
    {
         if (that == null)
         {
             return false;
         }
         else
         {
             if (that is Category)
             {
                 // select the fields you want to compare between the 2 objects

                 return this.Field == (that as Category).Field;
             }

             return false;
         }
    }
}
```

then in your code you can use **equals** method

```
Contract.Ensures(this.category.Equals(category))
```

Comment: OP is using a struct, not a class.