# Generic Types Hiding Each Other

Tags: c#, generics

Given the interfaces:

```
public interface IStorable<TPk>
{
    TPk ID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And

```
public interface ICacheHolder<TCached,TPk> where TCached : IStorable<TPk>
{
    ...
    TCached GetValueByID(TPk id);
    ...
}
```

And the concrete implementation:

```
public class BasicCacheHolder<TCached, TPk>: ICacheHolder<TCached, TPk> where TCached : IStorable<TPk>
{
    ...
    public TCached GetValueByID(TPk id)
    {
        return CacheEntries.SingleOrDefault(ce => ce.Value.ID == id);
    }
}
```

I get the error that "Operator '==' cannot be applied to the operands of type 'TPk' and 'TPk', Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'TPk' and 'TPk'"

I assume this is because one of the TPk generic types is hiding the reference to the other TPk, but attempting to rename them appears to break my code.

How do I fix this issue?

**EDIT**

CachedEntry is a very simple class of the following:

```
public class CacheEntry<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime RetrievedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `CacheEntries`?

Comment: It's a List<CacheEntry<T>>. Added CacheEntry to the question. It's a very simple data holder with just two fields; I could have used a tuple, but I wanted the fields to be named.

Comment: See the duplicate.  Use `EqualityComparer<TPk>.Default.Equals(ce.Value.ID, id)` instead.

Comment: `operator==` needs to be determined compile-time. Since it's definition is `BasicCacheHolder<TCached, TPk>`, there's still no type `TPk` that contains that operator. It cannot assume `TPk : class`, so I'd opt for a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c