# simple generic type compare

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a `MyUser` class with a generic identifier type. The `UserManager` class has a method `GetByIdentifier` which compares the given identifier with the known user identifiers. The problem is that I get the following error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TUserIdentifier' and 'TUserIdentifier'

```
public MyUser<TIdentifier>
{
    public TIdentifier Identifier { get; set; }
}

public class UserManager<TUser, TUserIdentifier>
    where TUser : MyUser<TUserIdentifier>
{
    protected List<TUser> userStore = new List<TUser>();
    protected TUser GetByIdentifier(TUserIdentifier identifier)
    {
        return userStore.FirstOrDefault(c => c?.Identifier == identifier);
    }
}
```

---

When I change the signature of the `UserManager` to the following I cannot define simple types as `int`, `string` ect as the `TUserIdentifier` anymore.

```
public class UserManager<TUser, TUserIdentifier>
    where TUser : MyUser<TUserIdentifier>
    where TUserIdentifier : class
```

A workaround would be to use the `Integer`, `String` etc. classes.

---

Another thing I tried doing is the following signature but it did not work

```
public class UserManager<TUser, TUserIdentifier>
    where TUser : MyUser<TUserIdentifier>
    where TUserIdentifier : IComparable
```

---

Should I go for the `Integer`, `String`, etc classes or is there another way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c

Comment: @CodeCaster as I understand this post is basicly saying that I have to use reference types for the compiler to know that the type can be comparable (operator can be applyed). Therefore I have to use the reference type implementations of int, string etc. Is that right?

Comment: Further you could use where TUserIdentifier : object. This should work I think.

Comment: @Dr.Fre: The highest voted answer (not the accepted one) says you can do this: `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y)` which seems to probably be the best way to do it.

Comment: Ah I got to keep reading to the end of such posts instead of just creating a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the compiler can not be sure that you are not mistakenly performing a reference equality check between two value types; `ReferenceEquals(1, 1)` will *always* be `false`, reference equality doesn't make sense with value types!

Because your generic types are not constrained to reference types (`class` constraint) the compiler simply dissallows the `==` operator because its default implementation is precisely reference equality.

To avoid this issue simply use the virtual `Equals` method.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Dr.Fre Consider, if possible, constraining `TUserIdentifier` to `IEquatable<TUserIdentifier>` to avoid unnecessary boxing.