# Trying to define a == and != operator for my struct, but I keep getting the "Operator `==' cannot be applied to operands..."

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, struct, operators, operand

I am trying to implement cartesian 2D integer coordinate system. I have managed to get +, -, * and / operators working. However, after implementing the == operator in the same way I am getting errors.

My struct is defined as follows:

```
public struct IntVector2 : IEquatable<IntVector2>
{
    // properties
    public int x { get; private set; }
    public int y { get; private set; }

    // constructors
    public IntVector2(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // I have removed the XML documentation and operator definitions here
}
```

NB: I implemented `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode` according to the .NET guidelines. Hence the `IEquateable<IntVector2>`

I have also defined the following operators (and many more) within the struct body:

```
public static bool operator ==(IntVector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    return (a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y);
}

public static bool operator != (IntVector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}

// Once again I removed the XML documentation
```

And the following overrides:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (!(obj is IntVector2))
    {
        return false;
    }

    IntVector2 intVect2 = (IntVector2)obj;
    return (x == intVect2.x && y == intVect2.y);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return (x * 31 + y);
}
```

In an effort to find a pre-existing answer, I investigated the following links:

- [Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)
- https://coding.abel.nu/2014/09/net-and-equals/ --- info and
  demonstration of equality operator being used
- msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c35t2ffz.aspx --- Equality operators
- msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h9bszxx(v=vs.100).aspx --- MSDN
  guidelines for implementing equality operators

All my other operators work fine, but when I try to compare the equality of 2 `IntVector2`s, I get errors. For example:

```
void Foo(IntVector2 intVectA, IntVector2 intVectB)
{
    if (intVectA.Equals(intVectB))
    {
        IntVector2 C = intVectA + intVectB;
        bool isEqual = intVectA == intVectB;
    }
}
```

Gives the error

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'IntVector2' and 
>       'IntVector2'

For context I am using this as a learning experience. I can get away without it (using `intVectA.x == intVectB.x && intVectA.y == intVectB.y`), but if I just go around the issue I will never learn why this is an error.

Also, my struct compiles completely without any errors.

Comment: You are missing the `==` implementation `public static bool operator ==(IntVector2 a, IntVector2 b)`

Comment: You might consider implementing `IComparable<IntVector2>` as well, so the struct can be used with generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to compare an `IntVector2` to another `IntVector2`, but your implementations of the `==` and `!=` operators take an `IntVector2` and a `Vector2`. I don't see any other mention of a class or struct called `Vector2` in your question. Is that a typo? The operators work fine for me if I change them to:

```
public static bool operator ==(IntVector2 a, IntVector2 b) { ... }
public static bool operator !=(IntVector2 a, IntVector2 b) { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, that was the correct answer. I had meant to implement equality operators with both Vector2 and IntVector2, but didn't realise I hadn't defined the one for both IntVector2's

Thanks for that. I spent many many hours trying to understand the problem and was over-complicating the issue.