# Comparing structs in a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

Here's a simplified case of what I'm struggling with:

```
public bool CompareStruct<S>(S a, S b) where S : struct
{
  return a == b;
}
```

The above will not compile with the error `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'S' and 'S'`.

Normally, I wouldn't be surprised. But I've indicated that `S` is a struct - so why can't I compare the two parameters?

I don't think [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c) has any relevancy here - after all, I'm working with `struct` types, not reference types.

Comment: `where S : IEquatable<S>` and `a.Equals(b)`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen OK, this solves the "how to get this to compile". But... why doesn't `==` work for `struct` in the above example? Shouldn't the compiler know it's capable of comparing the two parameters?

Comment: refer this post : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1166856/Equality-Operator-equalsequals-and-Value-Types-in

Comment: But you cannot compare arbitrary structs with `==` anyway, why would you expect it to work in generic method?

Comment: @Evk Hmm, good point. In my real-case I'm working with classes which all have an ID parameter which is always a well know value type like `string`, `Guid` or `int` (which fit the `where X : struct` definition). I guess I forgot that generic a generic `struct` might not have a `==` operator implemented. I guess this is the answer in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that the default behavior of `==` in C# is reference equality. Reference equality in structs makes no sense because it will always return `false`.

The compiler has no way of knowing if `==` has been overloaded and `S` has value equality semantics and therefore disallows its use.

To get around this, use `Equals` and consider constraining `S` to `IEquatable<S>` if appropiate to avoid unnecessary boxing operations.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you specify the constraint that the generic type parameter is `struct` **i.e. ValueType**, it is not necessary that the `struct` which calls this method has provided the overload implementation for `==` and `!=` operator for it, as for custom value types, when we define it we need to provide the `==` and `!=` operator overloads for them to be used.

An alternate can be to use `Object.Equals` method or call the `Equals()` method on it's own instance like:

```
public bool CompareStruct<S>(S a, S b) where S : struct
{
  return a.Equals(b);
}
```

or:

```
public bool CompareStruct<S>(S a, S b) where S : struct
{
  return Object.Equals(a,b);
}
```

The point to remember is that but the equality operator is by default not available for value types unless you overload the `==` operator for that type and for reference types using `==` operator does is checking for reference equality so that's why applying constraint to `class` works fine.

I once wrote a post about this which might be helpful which can be read at [this link (Equality Operator (==) and Value Types in C#)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1166856/Equality-Operator-equalsequals-and-Value-Types-in)

Comment: Constraining to `class` removes the compile time error and the type doesn't necessarily implement `==` either. The important fact missing in your answer (which you most certainly know about but the OP might not) is that `==` defaults to reference equality which makes no sense with value types.

Comment: you are right, i have mentioned that the case is specific to `struct` ValueType

Comment: The problem with using `Object.Equals` is that it will box `a` and `b` which is undesirable in tight-loops and other high-performance code. A better approach would be to add a constraint `where S : struct, IEquatable<S>` and then use `a.Equals(b)` - assuming that `S` correctly implements `IEquatable<T>.Equals` when `a == default(S)`, which unfortunately many people still don't, argh.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `==` on user-defined ValueTypes unless you explicitly override the `==` and `!=` operators. This is because the default implementation for a `struct` doesn't implement these operators. For instance, the below doesn't compile:

```
struct Foo
{

}

void Main()
{
    Foo f1;
    Foo f2;

    if(f1 == f2) // The compiler complains here
    {

    }
}
```

So if you can't do that for known structs (by default), then you can't do that for generic structs (less information known at compile time) unless you provide more information (for example that this struct have to implement `IEquatable<S>`)

The above would work for classes because they uses reference equality by default when using `==`. That doesn't apply to Value Types because they are copied by value.