# C# templates with constraint

Tags: c#, templates

Why in this code fragment will be printed false? I checked that the contents of the stirngs are completely identical, but the output is not the one that was expected. Could this be due to the imposed constraint for the template?

```
public static void OpTest<T>(T s, T t) where T : class
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(s == t);
    }

    static void Main()

    {
        string s1 = "string";

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(s1);
        string s2 = sb.ToString();

        OpTest<string>(s1, s2);
        System.Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: `==` compares references; change `s == t` into `object.Equals(s, t)` and you'll get `true`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: in c# they are called generics, and they are actually a difference beast compared to templates. They share a lot in common, but they are different. Just think about class `List<T>:` it exists, already compiled, before you use it with something like `new List<MyCustomClass>`. c++ templates are compiled just when you use them in your code, (and in fact, most of stl ones are defined in some header files which are compiled only if included in some .cpp file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could this be due to the imposed constraint for the template?

The `==` operator in your generic method does *not* use the overloaded (`string`) version. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c) answer for more information about this.

So there is a difference between the `==` operator being used in this generic method:

```
public static void OpTest<T>(T s, T t) where T : class
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(s == t);
}
```

...and in this non-generic one:

```
public static void OpTest(string s, string t)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(s == t);
}
```

As suggested by @Dmitry Bychenko you could "fix" your generic method by using the `Equals` method to compare the elements instead of using the `==` operator:

```
public static void OpTest<T>(T s, T t) where T : class
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(Equals(s, t));
}
```

It's even better to use the default `EqualityComparer` for the type `T` as this avoids any boxing and casting:

```
public static void OpTest<T>(T s, T t) where T : class
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(s, t));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) (i.e int), `==` returns true if they have same values

For [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)(i.e class), `==` returns true if they refer to the same object.

For an exception case `string`, a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) too. `==` compares the values of the strings.

In your example, the method `OpTest` takes your string as a class. That means it compares if they are same objects, not by their value. So it returns `false`

That means, with that code:

```
string s1 = "string";    
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(s1);
string s2 = sb.ToString();

System.Console.WriteLine(s == t);
OpTest<string>(s1, s2);
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
```

Comment: That's just a part of the problem, for string operator == actually checks for string equality, not for reference equality. There is some big  difference between c++ templates and  c# generics, OP question just spotted one of them