# How to compare generics in where clause in linq query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I want to compare string of structs for now

```
public Entity GetByPropertyValue<ValueType>(string propertyName, ValueType value)
{
    var contact = (from contacts in OrganizationContext.CreateQuery("contact")
                 where (ValueType)contacts[propertyName] == value
                 select contacts).FirstOrDefault();

    return contact;
}
```

but the problem is:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ValueType' and
>   'ValueType'

If do it otherwise

```
where object.Equals((ValueType)contacts[propertyName], value)
```

it will not work unfortunately

> System.NotSupportedException: Invalid 'where' condition. An entity
>   member is invoking an invalid property or method.

Comment: as a general observation about code readability - `ValueType` is a bad choice for a generic type parameter - it gets *very* confusing to the reader whether that means "the generic type" vs `System.ValueType` - frankly, I'd probably just use `T` :)

Comment: can I ask about `contacts[propertyName]` - what is that? is `propertyName` a regular name of a property here? is `contacts[propertyName]` using a custom indexer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)

Comment: Marc, contacts here is Contact class but casted to its base class Entity so to get properties indexer is used

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a scenario where a manual expression-tree construction is warranted. I can't test this without your code, but *something like*:

```
public Entity GetByPropertyValue<T>(string propertyName, T value)
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity));
    var body = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(p, propertyName),
        Expression.Constant(value, typeof(T)));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, bool>>(body, p);

    return OrganizationContext.CreateQuery("contact").Where(lambda).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

the last line might also be possibly rewritten:

```
return OrganizationContext.CreateQuery("contact").FirstOrDefault(lambda);
```

Note that while this might look verbose, this is actually what the C# compiler is generating *anyway* for an expression-tree based predicate; so: it doesn't have any impact on the actual *performance* of the code - it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Mark for a solution! But when Expression.Equal() is executed it throws System.ArgumentException: ''emailaddress1' is not a member of type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity''

Comment: @SergeyAslanov and it would be correct! so: what *actually* is your object? it is presumably a sub-type of `Entity` - so: use that; I'm guessing `Contact` or something? there are almost certainly ways of doing it without knowing the type ahead of time - I would expect that the return type of `OrganizationContext.CreateQuery` has something like a `EntityType` property or similar, that you could use here