# C# Enums and Generics

Tags: c#, generics, enums

Why does the compiler reject this code with the following error?  (I am using `VS 2017` with `C# 7.3` enabled.)

> CS0019 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

```
public class GenericTest<T> where T : Enum
{
    public bool Compare(T a, T b)
    {
        return a == b;
    }
}
```

The version without generics is of course perfectly valid.

```
public enum A { ONE, TWO, THREE };

public class Test
{
    public bool Compare(A a, A b)
    {
        return a == b;
    }
}
```

Comment: `return a.Equals(b);`?

Comment: possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c

Comment: Interesting. `class`, `MyClass`, `delegate`, `Type`  doesn't have this limitation, `struct`, `enum`, `unmanaged`, `IMyInterface` have. In other words it is only allowed if compiler can be sure it's reference type.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: This works but I don't understand why.

Comment: @AnuViswan: The difference is that in my example the compiler should know it is an enum and thus should be comparable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler cannot rely on the operator `==` being implemented for every type provided for `T`. You could add a constraint to restrict `T` to `class`, but that would not allow you to use it for your enum, due to the enum not being a reference type. Adding `struct` as a constraint would also not allow you to use the operator because structs don't always have an implementation of the `==` operator, but you could use `a.Equals(b)` in that case instead.

Comment: It's more than that. `operator ==` has to be *static*, so it's not even part of the set of methods of T that could ever be used in a generic implementation.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Right, and it is discussed in more detail [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/equality-operator-with-inheritance-and-generics-in-c-sharp/). However, the answer is correct - use Equals in this case.