# I am writing a generic <T> list of an array, I am trying to remove an item from index one and have the next item shift

Tags: c#

So when I do my remove it should look something like this:

`myArray = Shirt, Pants, Shoes, Hat`

`NewArray = Pants, Shoes, Hat, null`

My method I am using is:

```
public bool Remove(T items)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
   {
       if (items == array[i])
       {
          array[i] = array[i + 1];
          Count—-;
       }
       else 
       {
          Return False;
       }
   }
}
```

But I get an error code of

> operator == cannot be applied to operands of type T and T.

I tired to change the operator to just = but then I get another error that I cannot convert T to bool. I have googled and cannot find a solution.

Comment: You're telling the compiler that `items` can be **anything at all**, but you can't assume `==` will work with “anything at all”. So don't do that. What type is `myArray`? You need to say `public bool Remove(WhateverTypeMyArrayIs items)`

Comment: Wouldn't you want the array to **not** have nulls? And what if the value appears more than once? What if it appears in an index other than `0`? (by the way, you mentioned index `1` in your question. I think you meant index `0`).

Comment: You should use .Equals() or .ReferenceEquals(). But your "array[i] = array[i + 1];" is ambiguous: what do you you want to do? Because you have List<> or other predefined classes that perhaps match your case.

Comment: Please share the entire code for your class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)

Comment: Your code won't compile. Consider changing your title to be clear and short.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot I'm not sure of, for what you are trying to do:

But if I assume you want a generic class, something like this should work:

```
public static T[] RemoveFirst(T[] items)
{
    T[] result = new T[items.Count() - 1];      

    for (int i = 1; i < items.Count(); i++)
    {           
        result[i - 1] = items[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Things that I think you should remove:

```
if (items == array[i])
```

What do you want this comparrison to do? Because currently you are saying:

```
If thisArray == thisParticularInstanceInTheArray
```

which will always be false. `T != T[i]` doesn't make sense.

An additional thought, perhaps you are trying to do a RemoveAt(int x) method? and not a remove first?

If so: That comparison should be more like this would work:

```
public static T[] RemoveAt(T[] items, int X)
{
    T[] result = new T[items.Count() - 1];      

    int indexOfLastResult = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (i != X)
        {
            result[indexOfLastResult] = items[i];               
            indexOfLastResult++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```