# Blazor generic component with eventcallback

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I created a Component to which the parent component can bind to. Here is a minified example:

```
<input @bind=@Value />
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Value
    {
        get => _Value;
        set
        {
            if (_Value == value) return;
            _Value = value;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }
}
```

It is working and the parent component can bind to the value and gets the updates.

I want to make the component generic now. That means, that I want the parent component to be able to also bind an int value.
I tried using typeparam, but then this line

```
if (_Value == value) return;
```

was not working anymore.

How do I make this component generic?

Comment: what is the return type? You need to define the return type, if it is int return 0; if it is string return ""; ant etc. you create a templated component. take a took at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/390974/41403 for comparing generic types

Comment: Also check out how the `InputBase` components use the same method: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputBase.cs (see line 76)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare generic types directly using `==`, you need to have a method of comparing.

The correct way to do this is explained by his highness @JonSkeet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/390974/41403) by using `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y);`

So your comparison code (assuming the generic type is `TItem`) is:

```cs
[Parameter] public EventCallback<TItem> ValueChanged { get; set; }

[Parameter] public TItem Value
   {
      get => _Value;
      set
         {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_Value, value)) return;
            _Value = value;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
         }
    }
```