# Why doesn't List<T>.RemoveAll remove any items when I compare with ==?

Tags: c#, generics, containers, operator-overloading

I have a weird problem. Somehow, this code doesn't delete any items:

```
    public static int RemoveAll<T>(this List<T> container, T item) where T : class
    {
       return container.RemoveAll(i => i == item));
    }
```

Even though I'm getting `(i == item): true` in the VS Watch Window on a few of them.

When I re-write the code like this, it *DOES* wrok...

```
    public static int RemoveAll<T>(this List<T> container, T item)
    {
        int n = 0;
        while (container.Remove(item)) { ++n; }
        return n;
    }
```

Am I missing a secret about `this List<T>` being pass-by-value? The list doesn't change while inside the function either.

I'm calling it like this:

```
    List<string> completedTasks = new List<string>();
    string taskId = ...;
    ...
    completedTasks.RemoveAll(taskId);
```

Comment: How are you using the first RemoveAll method?

Comment: try to use the `Object.Equals` in your predicate. See the remarks on how List.Remove compares the objects.

Comment: @Chetan There is no LINQ `RemoveAll` method.  If you meant the List remove all method, it accepts a predicate, not an object to remove.

Comment: He's using `List<T>.RemoveAll`

Comment: Probably really has to do with Equals, ReferenceEquals, == and also string Interning. Likely the values are the same string, but it's not an interned string, so it's different instances and == does a ref check while Remove Item uses string.Equals with does an ordinal value comparison.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c) You should use `where T : IEquatable<T>` then you can compare using `i => i.Equals(item)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method uses the `==` operator (where both parameters are `object`, note that the generic method won't be able to find any overloads of this operator for that specific type).  The second method uses `object.Equals`.

Thus the first method will always compare the references of the two objects to see if they refer to the same object, the second method does whatever the `Equals` method is overridden to do.  Since you appear to want to use the `Equals` method for equality in this case (since you've stated that's the one that has the correct result), you simply need to use `object.Equals` rather than `==` when using `RemoveAll` to get that correct result.

Comment: But why is it enough to use == for strings outside this context? if (taskId == "task1b") works fine. And why does the Watch Window show the expected result?

Comment: @LucBloom Because those strings are statically typed as strings in your example, so the compiler can call the string overload of the `==` operator.  The generic method can't do that, as it doesn't know what the type is at compile time.  It can only use the object overload.

Comment: Aha, so it isn't like with C++ where it basically compiles duplicates of the code for each type so the compiler can optimize and recognize very specifically what types its dealing with. Now I know why it needs the : constraints so quickly and why I can't Duck-type a function call inside a generic. Thank you for this info, it helps me expand my mental model of how the language operates.