# C# Gives CS0019 Error: Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

Im trying to convert AVL tree to Generic but I faced couple of type errors.

> Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

```
 private Node RecursiveInsert(Node current, Node n)
{
    if (current == null)
    {
        current = n;
        return current;
    }
    else if (n.data < current.data) // Gives Error        {
        current.left = RecursiveInsert(current.left, n);
        current = balance_tree(current);
    }
    else if (n.data > current.data) // Gives Error        {
        current.right = RecursiveInsert(current.right, n);
        current = balance_tree(current);
    }
    return current;
}
```

///

```
 public class Node
{
    public T data { get; set; }
    public Node left { get; set; }
    public Node right { get; set; }
    public Node(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
public Node root;
```

Comment: If the type of data is not clear, it is not able to make a comparsion

Comment: As an example, what if `T` is an `Action<IQueryable<SomeCustomObject>>`.  What comparison is `<` and `>` meant to perform?  Perhaps you want to include a constraint on the type of `T` in `Node<T>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)

Comment: If you defined a custom type like `new { first = "fred", last = "flintstone" }` then what would `<` mean between two such types? Or perhaps between tuples of numbers, etc?

Comment: Did you mean to define `public class Node<T> { }` otherwise the class has no idea what T is

Comment: Is [this the original source code](https://simpledevcode.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/avl-tree-in-c/) you are working from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: somehow I managed to cut out a code snippet before I posted this.

First of all, the generic type in the Node class needs to implement the ICompareable interface to do this.

```
 public class Node<T> where T : ICompareable
 {
     public T data { get; set; }
     public Node<T> left { get; set; }
     public Node<T> right { get; set; }
     public Node<T>(T data)
     {
         this.data = data;
     }
 }
```

Second of all, ICompareable doesn't overload the '<' and '>' operators. You need to do something like this instead

```
else if (n.data.CompareTo(current.data) < 0) {
    current.left = RecursiveInsert(current.left, n);
    current = balance_tree(current);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a generic comparer from `Comparer<T>.Default`.

```
public class Node
{
    public static readonly IComparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
}
```

Then you can use it to compare generic types.

```
int c = Node.comparer.Compare(n.data, current.data);

if (c < 0) {
    current.left = RecursiveInsert(current.left, n);
    current = balance_tree(current);
}
else if (c > 0) {
    current.right = RecursiveInsert(current.right, n);
    current = balance_tree(current);
}
```