# How to implement different comparison for IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, comparison, ienumerable

Currently, I compare it this way [(from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/390974/312896):

```
bool foo<T>(T expected, T actual) {
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(expected, actual);
}
```

It works for basic types but not for `IEnumerable<T>`. How can I make it work for `IEnumerable<T>` like `SequenceEqual`?

EDIT: I tried the version of David L but it doesn't work either with arrays or with lists.

Comment: How do you expect the default EqualityComparer to work in a manner other than it is working? You'd need to provide your own EqualityComparer. How do you intend to call this?

Comment: @DavidL I don't know. I am open to ideas.

Comment: Do you have two sequences, and you want to compare them element by element, using a specialized comparer for comparing each pair of elements?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I updated the question. I want the function to work with IEnumerable's.  Currently, I don't want a specialized comparer for elements, I expect them to be ints.

Comment: So you want to keep the signature `bool foo<T>(T expected, T actual)`, but include a special handling for the case where `T` is `IEnumerable<T2>`. Essentially you want a variant of the [`Object.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals) (`public static bool Equals (object objA, object objB)`), that has the additional constraint of `objA` and `objB` having the same type, and including a special equality rule for a specific type of `T`. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is nothing that prevents you from calling `SequenceEquals` directly, you can certainly wrap that call in helper methods. Note that `SequenceEquals` will compare index by index. You can also pass it an `IEqualityComparer<T>` instance if you want to override how the comparison is handled.

```
bool foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> expected, IEnumerable<T> actual)
{
    return expected.SequenceEqual(actual);
}

bool foo<T>(List<T> expected, List<T> actual)
{
    return expected.SequenceEqual(actual);
}

bool foo<T>(T[] expected, T[] actual)
{
    return expected.SequenceEqual(actual);
}

bool foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> expected, IEnumerable<T> actual,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    return expected.SequenceEqual(actual, comparer);
}
```

Testing with the following returns true as expected:

```
IEnumerable<int> expected = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
IEnumerable<int> actual = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

List<int> expected2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> actual2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

int[] expected3 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] actual3 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

Console.WriteLine(foo(expected, actual));
Console.WriteLine(foo(expected2, actual2));
Console.WriteLine(foo(expected3, actual3));
```

and returns false for the following:

```
IEnumerable<int> expected = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
IEnumerable<int> actual = new List<int> { 1, 3, 2 };
```

---

The benefit of the above approach is that you get compile-time overloads for each collection type that you want to explicitly support. However, if you want to implicitly support all collection types, you can expand your current `boo foo<T>` method as follows:

```
bool foo<T>(T expected, T actual)
{
    // check that both T parameters implement IEnumerable 
    // (meaning they are a collection)
    if (expected is IEnumerable expectedEnumerable && 
        actual is IEnumerable actualEnumerable)
    {
        var expectedEnumerator = expectedEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
        var actualEnumerator = actualEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
        
        while (true)
        {
            // Determine if the enumerators have a next element
            var hasExpected = expectedEnumerator.MoveNext();
            var hasActual = actualEnumerator.MoveNext();

            // Either we have no elements or successfully iterated both
            if (!hasExpected && !hasActual)
            {
                return true;
            }

            // One of the enumerators has a value while the other does not.
            if ((hasExpected && !hasActual) || (!hasExpected && hasActual))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // check the equality of the two current elements
            if (!expectedEnumerator.Current.Equals(actualEnumerator.Current))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // fall back to your original equality comparison because
    // one or both parameters do not implement IEnumerable
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(expected, actual);
}
```

This again returns true for the three collection cases I listed above, and false for the following test cases:

```
IEnumerable<int> expected4 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
IEnumerable<int> actual4 = new List<int> { 1, 3, 2 };

List<int> expected5 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<int> actual5 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

int[] expected6 = new int[] { 2, 3 };
int[] actual6 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

Console.WriteLine(foo(expected4, actual4));
Console.WriteLine(foo(expected5, actual5));
Console.WriteLine(foo(expected6, actual6));
```

Comment: I want to be able to call `foo` for all parameters. I'm OK if I need to overload it.

Comment: @Yola that's fine. I've updated the naming. If you have an overload that takes `IEnumerable<T>`, it can live side-by-side with your current `foo<T>(T expected, T actual)` method.

Comment: I just tried with arrays and lists and it always chooses `foo<T>(T expected, T actual)`. Could you provide MWE?

Comment: @Yola Because of your `foo<T>` method's contract, you need to add unique overloads per collection type. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, it works this way. But this way I need to update it for every collection I use. Doesn't seem like a good design:( Is it not possible in C# to do it in a more general fashion?

Comment: The issue is your `foo<T>` contract which is somewhat inflexible. That said, you can modify your original method to handle all `IEnumerable` cases. I've updated my answer.