# Applying '==' operator to generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)

I have a DatabaseLookup{} class where the parameter T will be used by the lookup methods in the class. Before lookup, I want to see if T was already looked up with something like

```
if (T == previousLookupObject) ...
```

This doesn't compile at all. What is preventing me from making a simple comparison like this?

Comment: Is `T` referring to the generic type or an actual variable of the generic.  `T` is usually used as the name of the generic type.  Not an object but a type.  Try defining a variable of type `T`.

Comment: And then use `thisObject.Equals(previousLookupObject)` instead of `==`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`T` is the type parameter. If your `previousLookupObject` is an object of `Type`, you need to do `typeof(T) == previousLookupObject`.

If `previousLookupObject` is variable of type  `T`, you need to have an actual object of `T` to compare it to.

If you want to find out if `previousLookupObject` is of type `T`, you need to use the `is` operator: `if (previousLookupObject is T)`.

Answer (score 8):

`T` is type, `previousLookupObject` is (I suppose) an object instance. So you are comparing apples to oranges. Try this:

```
if (previousLookupObject is T)
{
    ...    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following links:

[Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)

[c# compare two generic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488250/c-compare-two-generic-values)

Answer (score 0):

What type is `previousLookupObject`?  Generic type parameters are types, and can't be used as normal object references.