# EqualityComparer<T>.Default isn't clever enough

Tags: c#, .net, enums, equals, iequalitycomparer

I was reading the source code of `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` and found that it's not so clever. Here is an example:

```
enum MyEnum : int { A, B }
EqualityComparer<MyEnum>.Default.Equals(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B)
//is as fast as 
EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(0, 1)

enum AnotherEnum : long { A = 1L, B = 2L }
//is 8x slower than
EqualityComparer<long>.Default.Equals(1L, 2L)
```

The reason is obvious from the source code of the private method in EqualityComparer.

```
private static EqualityComparer<T> CreateComparer()
{
    //non-important codes are ignored
    if (c.IsEnum && (Enum.GetUnderlyingType(c) == typeof(int)))
    {
        return (EqualityComparer<T>) RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter((RuntimeType) typeof(EnumEqualityComparer<int>), c);
    }
    return new ObjectEqualityComparer<T>();
}
```

We can see `EqualityComparer<int>.Default`,`EqualityComparer<MyEnum>.Default` and `EqualityComparer<long>.Default` get a wise comparer whose `Equals` method looks like:

```
public static bool Equals(int x, int y)
{
    return x == y;  //or return x.Equals(y); here 
                    //I'm not sure, but neither causes boxing
}

public static bool Equals(MyEnum x, MyEnum y)
{
    return x == y;  //it's impossible to use x.Equals(y) here 
                    //because that causes boxing
}
```

The above two are *clever*, but `EqualityComparer<AnotherEnum>.Default` is unlucky, from the method we can see at last it gets a `ObjectEqualityComparer<T>()`, whose `Equals` method probably looks like:

```
public static bool Equals(AnotherEnum x, AnotherEnum y)
{
    return x.Equals(y);   //too bad, the Equals method is from System.Object
                       //and it's not override, boxing here!
                       //that's why it's so slow
}
```

I think this condition `Enum.GetUnderlyingType(c) == typeof(int)` is pointless, if the underlying type of an enum is of type int, the method can *convert* the default comparer of int to this enum. But why can't an enum based on long? It's not so hard i think? Any special reason? Constructing a comparer like `x == y` isn't so hard for enum, right? Why at last it gives a slow `ObjectEqualityComparer<T>` for enums(even it works correctly)?

Comment: as a side note it is possible to write your own which does the right thing. But I haven't seen a way to do it without either code generation or C++/CLI. I couldn't find a way, even with unsafe{} to allow reinterpret casts via void* in c# with generic types.

Comment: I just published a small library on GitHub that lets you make the default equality comparer as clever as you want: https://github.com/smartcaveman/undefault

Answer (score 7):

I think that there's simply no compelling reason for the team responsible to add this feature. All features have an implementation cost which includes (among others) the time to document, code and test.

There are a couple of compelling reasons why this particular feature has not been picked over others so far (and will probably never make the cut IMO):

- It only applies to a very narrow scenario (comparing `enums` backed by something other than an `int`, and doing that in some inner loop)
- There is a very straightforward and discoverable solution if it causes you a problem (write your own comparer)

Comment: Yes, I think the `narrowness` of the scenario is the point. If they had considered long, they should have included byte, short etc. too...

Comment: But still, if they took the effort to add the condition, it must had been for a reason.

Comment: @FrantišekŽiačik: Covering the 99% case would be a reason :)

Comment: I didn't make myself clear. If I cite Danny Chen, *"I think this condition `Enum.GetUnderlyingType(c) == typeof(int)` is pointless*, if it's true, then adding it would narrow the coverage from 100% down to 99%. So they should have a good reason for this, shouldn't they.

Comment: Ah, I looked at the code again and now I see, they had to use a concrete `EnumEqualityComparer<>`, that's the reason.