# Direct comparisons of C# Value types

Tags: c#, generics, comparison, operators

I have read the following statement regarding to the comparison of C# value types
in C# in Depth, Second Edition several times.

page 77,

> When a type parameter is unconstrained (no constraints are applied to it), you can use == and != operators, but only to compare a value of that type with null. You can’t compare two values of type T with each other.
>
> ...
>
> When a type parameter is constrained to be a value type, == and != can’t be used with it at all.

If I understand (I don't think so) it correctly, it basically tells me that you cannot
use == or != to compare two value types. Why why why?

It will be better if a simple example can be given for this case. Can someone give me
a little idea what the above paragraph tries to convey?

Comment: I suspect this is to avoid confusion with operator overloading, since an overloaded == operator would not be used when the generic type parameter is a value type.  You can use Object.Equals, however, which well-behaved value types will implement and which will have the same behavior as == (for well-behaved types).

Comment: @Dan Bryant, it's not only to avoid confusion. There's no guarantee that a value type supports the == and != operators, and we *can't use the System.Object implementation for value types, because testing reference equality only works on boxed instances.* Well, we could in theory specify that the operands be boxed in order to use the reference equality check, but then the expression would always be false, which is clearly useless.

Comment: @phoog, the static `Object.Equals` will actually call the Equals implementation of the Object (even if it's a boxed value type), so it's a valid way to compare even value types.  It also handles comparison of null with value types.  `Object.ReferenceEquals` explicitly forces the check to be for reference equality, which can be helpful in cases where a reference type overrides the equality operator, but has a bug for the null comparison case (I've encountered this before with a third-party API.)

Comment: @Dan Bryant, yes, static (and also instance) object.Equals will do what you describe. The problem is that the == operator does not do this, and therefore it's impossible to meaningfully apply that operator in the case where a generic type parameter is a value type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It simply means this when constraining to a value type (second paragraph)

```
static bool TryToCompare<T>(T first, T second) where T : struct
{
    return first == second; // not legal
    return first.Equals(second); // legal
}
```

Without the value-type constraint on the generic, it also says this (first paragraph)

```
static bool TryToCompare<T>(T first, T second) 
{
    return first == second; // not legal
    return first == null; // legal
    return first.Equals(second); // legal
}
```

If you constrain `T` to a reference type, you can get away with using `==`

```
static bool TryToCompare<T>(T first, T second) where T : class
{
    return first == second; // legal
    return first == null; // legal
    return first.Equals(second); // legal
}
```

Comment: the first example on your second function fails b/c we don't have any constraint on T and T may be struct or class. Is that correct? -thx

Comment: More or less. There is no guarantee a value type `T` defines the `==` operator. For more on this topic, I would suggest you see this question and the top answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808057/operator-cant-be-applied-to-type-t

Comment: +1: basically I only use `==` and `!=` against constants. If I'm not mistaken, you can also use `default(T)` for evaluation. Otherwise, I use `Equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

Objects aren't comparable because a comparison using == is testing whether the reference is the same (the memory address). You would normally use if (string1.Equals(string2)).

Something I don't understand is that I have seen circumstances where == works with strings, and circumstances where it doesn't.

Comment: From a results POV, `==` and `string1.Equals(string2)` shouldn't be any different. They're calculated in different ways, but for short strings, `Equals` has a slight speed advantage. Good article here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-equals

Comment: On strings, you start to see "unexpected" results when comparisons are made against string *as* objects. Consider `string x = "ONE"; string y = string.Format("ON{0}", "E"); bool b = x == y; bool c = (object)x == (object)y;` `b` will be true, `c` will be false. However, change `y` to be `string y = "ONE";`, and now `c` will also be true.

Comment: If the reference to either string operand has a compile-time type of object, then == will compile to a reference equality check. If they are both string-type references, you'll get the string implementation of the operator.