# Converting an generic IDictionary to an ASP.NET MVC IEnumerable<SelectListItem>: choosing the Selected item

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, generics, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is the full implementation I am considering:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Utils {
    public static class IDictionaryExt {
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems<T, R>(this IDictionary<T, R> dic, T selectedKey) {
            return dic.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Value.ToString(), Value = x.Key.ToString(), Selected=(dynamic)x.Key == (dynamic)selectedKey });
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the equality check using the dynamic casts: `(dynamic)x.Key == (dynamic)selectedKey`. Is this the best way to check equality between `selectedKey` and `x.Key` here? Based on @Gabe's comment in [Operator '==' can't be applied to type T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808057/operator-cant-be-applied-to-type-t), I believe it is: overload resolution is deferred to to runtime, but we do get "normal" overload resolution (i.e. considering `ValueType`s and other `Object`s with `==` overloads versus `Object`s with default reference equality).

Comment: Why would you want to cast to dynamic? Simply call `x.Key.Equals(selectedKey)` and let it determine it for you.

Comment: @Tejs - yep, that's pretty much my question: which should I do 1) `(dynamic)x.Key == (dynamic)selectedKey` 2) `x.Key.Equals(selectedKey)` 3) `(object)x.Key == (object)selectedKey`. I thought #2 as you suggested would be fine, but then I doubted my confidence and thought I might be missing something.

Comment: @Tejs - and alas, there are even more options already given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to handle this situation is to use [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx)

```
return dic.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Value.ToString(), Value = x.Key.ToString(), Selected= EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x.Key, selectedKey) });
```

Comment: Thanks @Bala R - how would this differ from just using `x.Key.Equals`? I also wonder if I were to change `dic` to a `Dictionary<T,R>`, whether there would be any merit to doing `dic.Comparer.Equals(selectedKey)`...

Comment: @Stephen `x.Key.Equals()` is not type safe since it takes an object; `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals()` is.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `x.Key.Equals` you can pull the comparison into a Func:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems<T, R>(this IDictionary<T, R> dic, Func<T, bool> selectedKey)
{
    return dic.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Value.ToString(), Value = x.Key.ToString(), Selected = selectedKey(x.Key) });
}
```

then call it as so:

```
var list = sampleDictionary.ToSelectListItems(k => k == "Some Key");
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew -- is there any reason I wouldn't want to use `x.Key.Equals`?

Comment: @Stephen It would certainly work, my suggestion just allows for a little more extensibility in the comparison.

Comment: indeed, great idea, I'll make an overload for it if ever needed.