# What's the most performant way to compare two values for equality?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, boxing

Say I have a generic method in C# that accepts two values of type T:

```
public void M<T>(T a, T b)
{
    ...
}
```

Inside body of M() I wish to compare both input values for equality. Since I don't know anything about their run-time types except that they are the same type, I could do this using the object.Equals() static method and let it choose the best way:

```
public void M<T>(T a, T b)
{
    if (object.Equals(a, b))
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem I see here is needless boxing of the two values when T isn't a reference type. I would like to avoid that penalty, because M() is called very frequently.

My question is: is there a better way to go about this? I'm obviously interested in a solution that wouldn't involve too much analysis of T up front, which would offset gains from boxing evasion.

TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# compare two generic values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488250/c-compare-two-generic-values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(a,b))
{...}
```

this uses `IEquatable<T>` when available to avoid boxing, and handles value-types, reference-types, and "lifted" usage against `Nullable<T>` to avoid boxing in almost all scenarios.

When `IEquatable<T>` is *not* available, it must defer to `object.Equals`, so boxing of value-types may occur.

Comment: Perfect! I knew about this class, but wasn't really able to connect the dots since I rarely use it in my own code. Thanks, Marc!

Comment: I think I just found [boxing still happens with `IEquatable<> valuetypes` on mono (trunk)](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/648425ebe1af72b062b1810e86ada260be9104f0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/EqualityComparer.cs); I added [a comment to JbEvain's latest commit](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/648425ebe1af72b062b1810e86ada260be9104f0#commitcomment-460052) there to ask his opinion (I only spent a few minutes looking at monodis output here)

Comment: I would expect that running EqualityComparer<T>.Default once is usually going to take longer than using instance.Compare once, even in cases where the latter would require boxing.  The advantage of using EqualityComparer<T>.Default comes if one can use it once and then use the returned method on hundreds or thousands of value-type instances.  Note that only value types and *sealed* class types should implement IEquatable<T>; if I had my druthers, EqualityComparer<T>.Default would check for implementation of IDontUseEquatable and, for any class implementing it, use Object.Equals.

Comment: @supercat the strategy per `T` is cached in a field, so once it has been used *once*, all subsequent uses of `.Default` are pretty quick. It doesn't have to do any thinking - just a deference... but yes, capturing the return value into a variable is even better.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Thanks for the info.  BTW, do you agree that inheritable types shouldn't implement IEquatable<T>?