# String equality in generic class

Tags: c#, generics

What is the difference between **==** and **Equals** in generic class if T is a string.

I prepared sample code with 2 tests. TestMethod1 fails on 2nd assert, but TestMethod2 passes.

Source code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    class Foo<T> where T : class
    {
        public static bool Foo1(T item1, T item2)
        {
            return item1 == item2;
        }

        public static bool Foo2(T item1, T item2)
        {
            return item1.Equals(item2);
        }
    }

    [TestCase]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var name = "str" + 1;
        // passes
        Assert.IsTrue(Foo<string>.Foo2(name, "str1"));
        // fails !
        Assert.IsTrue(Foo<string>.Foo1(name, "str1"));
    }

    [TestCase]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        // passes
        Assert.IsTrue(Foo<string>.Foo2("str1", "str1"));
        // also passes!
        Assert.IsTrue(Foo<string>.Foo1("str1", "str1"));
    }
}
```

Related question:
[c# compare two generic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488250/c-sharp-compare-two-generic-values)

Comment: What happens if you write 

     var name = "str" + 1;

In Test Method 2 instead of using the actual string

Comment: In your second test method, those string literals will be interned, and so will be the same object. That might be part of the behaviour you are observing.

Comment: The same, it fails on 2nd assert.
@Matt Jones Yes, know that.

Comment: Did either of these answers help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matt has already mentioned, half of your problem is interning.
And the other half is that the compiler has no idea about your type parameter being `string` and treats it like just some reference type, hence it calls `object`'s methods.
But don't take it on faith, let's take a look at IL.

`ceq` here tells us that there's no `==` operator overload, so reference check is performed on `box`ed arguments.

```
Foo`1.Foo1:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  box         Test+Foo<>.T
IL_0007:  ldarg.1     
IL_0008:  box         Test+Foo<>.T
IL_000D:  ceq         
IL_000F:  stloc.0     
IL_0010:  br.s        IL_0012
IL_0012:  ldloc.0     
IL_0013:  ret
```

On the other hand, here we can see `callvirt` of `System.Object.Equals` and at runtime it will be resolved into a call of whatever implementation actual type parameter has, i.e. `string.Equals`.

```
Foo`1.Foo2:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  box         Test+Foo<>.T
IL_0007:  ldarg.1     
IL_0008:  box         Test+Foo<>.T
IL_000D:  callvirt    System.Object.Equals
IL_0012:  stloc.0     
IL_0013:  br.s        IL_0015
IL_0015:  ldloc.0     
IL_0016:  ret
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `==` in this case resolves to `System.Reference.Equals`.

`.Equals` is a virtual method so the overridden version will be used, in this case it will be content comparison for string.

The first test compares a local variable to a literal (interned) string.

The second test compares the same interned string so both `==` and `Equals` return true.

If you change your `TestMethod1()` to this:

```
        Assert.IsTrue(Foo<string>.Foo1(name, name));
```

it will pass because you are comparing the same object, so the reference equality returns true.

Edit: If we add this method:

```
    public static bool Foo3(string item1, string item2)
    {
        return item1 == item2;
    }
```

Then the following test will return `true`:

```
    Assert.IsTrue(Foo<string>.Foo3(name, "str1"));
```

because C# will resolve `==` in this case to the string value check.

This question is really a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals), with additional generic complexity.

Edit 2:
OK, time to dive into the MSIL. `Foo1` looks like this:

```
.method public hidebysig static bool  Foo1(!T item1,
                                           !T item2) cil managed
{
  // Code size       20 (0x14)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] bool V_0)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  box        !T
  IL_0007:  ldarg.1
  IL_0008:  box        !T
  IL_000d:  ceq
  IL_000f:  stloc.0
  IL_0010:  br.s       IL_0012
  IL_0012:  ldloc.0
  IL_0013:  ret
} // end of method Foo`1::Foo1
```

You can see here it is using `ceq` which is *Push 1 (of type int32) if value1 equals value2, else push 0.*

Here is `Foo2`:

```
.method public hidebysig static bool  Foo2(!T item1,
                                           !T item2) cil managed
{
  // Code size       23 (0x17)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] bool V_0)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  box        !T
  IL_0007:  ldarg.1
  IL_0008:  box        !T
  IL_000d:  callvirt   instance bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object)
  IL_0012:  stloc.0
  IL_0013:  br.s       IL_0015
  IL_0015:  ldloc.0
  IL_0016:  ret
} // end of method Foo`1::Foo2
```

This uses `System.Object::Equals` - this is the virtual method and behaves as such, being overridden in the concrete type of the parameter - in this case `string`.

`Foo3` (which I added, which uses `==` on declared `string` parameters) looks like this:

```
.method public hidebysig static bool  Foo3(string item1,
                                           string item2) cil managed
{
  // Code size       13 (0xd)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] bool V_0)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldarg.1
  IL_0003:  call       bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string,
                                                                 string)
  IL_0008:  stloc.0
  IL_0009:  br.s       IL_000b
  IL_000b:  ldloc.0
  IL_000c:  ret
} // end of method Foo`1::Foo3
```

Here we observe explicit use of the `System.String::op_Equality(string, string)` which is the string value check comparison.

Comment: but `Assert.IsTrue(name == "str1");` will also pass even though references will be different. String has its own `== operator` and I am asking why it is not used in generic classes.

Comment: Because `Assert.IsTrue(name == "str1");` is comparing an explicitly declared `string` with an interned string so it is using the string value check version of `==`. In your generic method the object reference version of `==` is being used because that's how C# is resolving it.