# Why does Comparer<T>.Default exist in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I wonder for what reason we need to use Comparer.Default as calling `.Sort()` by default will call `CompareTo()` function? e.g.,

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
list.Sort();
list.Sort(Comparer<String>.Default);
```

Isn't `list.Sort()` totally equivalent to `list.Sort(Comparer<String>.Default)`? so what's the reason behind having `Comparer<T>.Default`?

Comment: Does `list.Sort()` automatically default to using `Comparer<>.Default` behind the scenes?

Comment: First, `List<T>.Sort()` is not the only time one needs an `IComparer<T>` implementation. Second, there are lots of different opinions you might get in answer to your question. That said, why do you think it not useful to have a single object that can be used, rather than having to create a new one each time you want to provide an `IComparer<T>`?

Comment: one example I can think of is comparing generic type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488250/c-sharp-compare-two-generic-values

Comment: It exists because it is doing a very untrivial job.  The troublemaker is `IComparable<T>`, an interface that a type *may* implement to customize the comparison.  But methods like Sort require a `Comparer<T>`.  Turning a generic interface into a class object is something that you cannot do in C#, the Default property implementation uses a backdoor provided by the CLR named CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter().  Note how the MSDN docs for IComparable recommend that you create your own Comparer instead.